# How to get "success" with jQuery AJAX email form

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a simple email form on a website - Processing it through AJAX using the jQuery library.

I know that the form is working because I am receiving the test email, but I will need for the user to know that their email has sent. Currently, **there is no event happening upon success. It should be replacing the form (in div #contactform) with a success message.** What am I missing here?

NOTE: I looked at the activity in Safari after submitting the form and it shows my process.php script, but it says "cancelled". Why is it doing this, and could it have something to do with why it is not showing a success message?

Here's my script:

HTML

```
<div id="contactform">
    <form id="churchcontact" action="" method="POST">

        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <span class="error error_name">Please enter your name</span>
                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
            </li>

            <li>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <span class="error error_email">Please enter your email address</span>
                <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
            </li>

            <li>
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <span class="error error_message">Please write a message</span>
                <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input class="formsubmit" type="submit" value="Send" />
            <li>
        </ul>

    </form>
    </div>
```

jQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    ////////////////////////////////////
    //// form submit                ////
    ////////////////////////////////////
    $('#churchcontact').submit(function() {


        ////////////////////////////////////
        //// validation                 ////
        ////////////////////////////////////
        $('.error').hide();

        //message
        var message = $('textarea#message').val();
        if(message == '') {
            $('.error_message').show();
            $('textarea#message').focus();
            var errors = 'true';
        }


        //email
        var email = $('input#email').val();
        var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length || email == '') {
            $('.error_email').show();
            $('input#email').focus();
            var errors = 'true';
        }

        //name
        var name = $('input#name').val();
        if(name == '') {
            $('.error_name').show();
            $('input#name').focus();
            var errors = 'true';
        }




        if(errors) {
            return false;
        } else {


            ////////////////////////////////////
            //// process                    ////
            ////////////////////////////////////

            var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;
            //alert (dataString);return false;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sites/all/modules/custom/churchcontact/process.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('#contactform').html("success!");
                }
            });



        }

        return false;

    });



});
```

PHP (process.php)

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$msg = $_POST['message'];


$recipient = '[my email]';
$subject = 'Website Test';

$message = '
Name: ' . $name
. ', Email: ' . $email
. ', Message: ' . $msg;


mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in process.php add an `echo` of `mail()`:

```
$res = mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo $res;        //if $res returns 1 that means mail was sent
```

ajax `success`:

```
...
success: function(data) {
    if(data == 1){
        message = "success!";
    }
    else{
        message = "Error";
    }    
    $('#contactform').empty().html(message);
   }
```

Comment: Only the one in the Safari Activity window: ".../process.php Cancelled".
But the script actually works because I do receive the email.

Comment: No. The form remains on the page (it is in #contactform) and the field values remain.
btw, I attempted to prompt an alert() upon success, and it also did nothing.

Comment: Thanks for you help! I tried your last suggestion, and actually, both work! I remembered that you often have to do more than press return in the address bar. To refresh the .js file, I had to also reload the page (cmd+r). Once I did that, the success message worked with your initial suggestion.